# Trying to start miner process from SSH but fails?

Tags: windows, ssh, drivers, cuda

I've set up SSH to my Windows 7 box at home. I'm connected to my box and trying to run a batch file that will start my dogecoin miner. When it runs cudaminer, I get this output:

> ```
>        *** CudaMiner for nVidia GPUs by Christian Buchner ***
>                  This is version 2014-02-09 (beta)
>     based on pooler-cpuminer 2.3.2 (c) 2010 Jeff Garzik, 2012 pooler
>
>         Cuda additions Copyright 2013,2014 Christian Buchner
>       LTC donation address: LKS1WDKGED647msBQfLBHV3Ls8sveGncnm
>       BTC donation address: 16hJF5mceSojnTD3ZTUDqdRhDyPJzoRakM
>       YAC donation address: Y87sptDEcpLkLeAuex6qZioDbvy1qXZEj4
> ```
>
> [2014-07-07 09:55:13] Unable to query CUDA driver version! Is an
>   nVidia driver installed?

It seems to be using some sort of screen context that the current session has. Since I'm running it via SSH, the context doesn't have a proper connection to the CUDA drivers. If I connect using Google Chrome's Remote Desktop (which I believe uses VNC) then I can run the batch just fine.

The batch file is one simple line just so I don't have to remember all the flags:

```
cudaminer.exe -H 1 -i 0 -C 1 -l F15x11 -o stratum+tcp://us1.captaindoge.com:3333 -O coreyog.conquest:conquest
```

It does work under most circumstances, such as when I'm in VNC or actually at the desktop with a local mouse and keyboard. I'm mostly concerned with SSH. How can I start this process in a way that it can connect to the CUDA drivers regardless of the "screen context" I'm starting it from?

Comment: Your trying to connect to the Cuda drivers through SSH?  That isn't going to be possible.

Comment: What makes this impossible?

Comment: The program is looking for the drivers on the device its being ran.  You can connect to another device through ssh and tell the software to use that device but the program wants the drivers on the machine its running on.

Comment: The machine can run the batch if I connect through it a different way (VNC works just fine). SSH may not be using the drivers, but the computer has the drivers and the video cards. Can I run the process on a different session that is using the drivers?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wish to not use e.g. VNC or Chrome's RemoteDesktop or TeamViewer / LogMeIn?

Comment: VNC is a desktop sharing application.  It makes sense it would work like that because your actually running it no the server and not the client.

Answer (score 0):

Well on Linux it's pretty straightforward, first you run e.g.:

```
xhost +localhost
```

On the remote machine, and then from a remote SSH session you can just set `DISPLAY`, e.g.:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 program and its options
```

I don't know if Windows would behave the same way, it doesn't run X so there would certainly be some other trickery involved behind the scenes.

Is there a particular reason why you wish to not use e.g. VNC or Chrome's RemoteDesktop or TeamViewer / LogMeIn?

You may also be better off with [PowerShell](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+start+application+remotely) here, it seems it has some remote execution capabilities. See also [common ways to run programs on remote (windows) computers](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/common-ways-run-programs-remote-computers).

---

One thing you might be able to do is really hack it; create for example a batch file that constantly loops on the remote machine, looking for the presence of, say, `startminer.bat`. If it finds it, it executes it, deletes it, then continues looping. Run that monitor batch file on startup and let it stay running (and run it from the machine, not from a remote SSH session).

Then from your remote session you can do e.g.:

```
echo cudaminer.exe blah blah > startminer.bat
```

And the "monitoring" script will find it and execute it in the remote session.

This is pretty ugly, and will make killing the process a lot harder (and monitoring its output impossible), but may work as a quick hack.

PowerShell or one of the other solutions from the search results above is a better tool for the job, however, and more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: It seems like overkill to VNC into a machine so I can run a script. Besides, I'm trying to learn more about SSH.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It's not really overkill if it's gets the job done sufficiently. SSH is worthy of learning, but the valuable lesson to be learned about SSH here is it might not be the right tool for every job. :)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Also it seems [PowerShell](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+start+application+remotely) has some remote execution capabilities; and would be a better tool for the job since it is designed for Windows from the start.

Comment: I don't know if I want to allow powershell to connect from outside the network. I feel I can better trust SSH.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I would ask about PowerShell security on a relevant SE site first, do some real research, and get actual credible information before shooting yourself in the foot trying to screw in a screw with a hammer.